# How do I install these libraries/codecs for Matlab?

Tags: video, codecs, matlab

I just installed matlab on my computer, seemingly successfully, but I've been trying to run a program, and I'm getting the following error:

```
>> reproduceResults
Warning: Directory already exists. 
> In reproduceResults at 14 
Processing ./data/baby.mp4
Error using VideoReader/init (line 429)
The file requires the following codec(s) to be installed on your system:
    video/x-h264


Error in VideoReader (line 132)
            obj.init(fileName);

Error in amplify_spatial_lpyr_temporal_iir (line 31)
    vid = VideoReader(vidFile);

Error in reproduceResults (line 20)
amplify_spatial_lpyr_temporal_iir(inFile, resultsDir, 10, 16, 0.4, 0.05, 0.1);

>>
```

For reference, the code that I'm trying to run is here:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/#code

I'm running reproduceResults.m, after downloading all of the video files that they provided.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

I can't find any answers on google that work. The one that I've tried is this:
http://memyselfandcomputer.blogspot.com/2011/01/matlab-2010-videox-h264-error-on-ubuntu.html

It doesn't seem to change anything though. Is there a way to get a more verbose output to help me debug/search better?